# is there any way to determine if an numpy array is record/structure array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I cannot find any way to determine if an array is record array or not:

```
>>> import numpy as npy
>>> c0=npy.array([1,2])
>>> c=c0.view(dtype=[('x',int),('y',int)])
>>> c
array([(1, 2)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

the type is always numpy.ndarray

```
>>> type(c)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> isinstance(c,npy.recarray)
False
```

the element type is always numpy.void

```
>>> type(c[0])
<type 'numpy.void'>
```

now I use dtype.fields to determine it:

```
>>> def isRecarray(a):
    return a.dtype.fields != None

>>> isRecarray(c0)
False
>>> isRecarray(c)
True
```

Is there any official way to determine if an array is record array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those are record arrays. [Per the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('x', float), ('y', int)])
>>> y = x.view(np.recarray)
>>> type(x), type(y)
(<type 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.core.records.recarray'>)
```

`ndarray.view` creates a new reference to the same memory, and as you call it also names the fields. There isn't a fundamental type difference between your `c0` and `c`, they're both ndarrays.

Comment: Besides recarrays, is there difference/way to see the difference between ndarrays and structured arrays?

Answer (score 4):

Since [metaperture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24814739/13395519)'s answer explained how to distinguish whether a numpy array is record array but not a *structured* array, [here's what I found in the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#manipulating-and-displaying-structured-datatypes):

> Both the `names` and `fields` attributes will equal `None` for unstructured arrays. The recommended way to test if a dtype is structured is with *if dt.names is not None* rather than *if dt.names*, to account for dtypes with 0 fields.

So in your example,

```
>> import numpy as npy
>> c0=npy.array([1,2])
>> c=c0.view(dtype=[('x',int),('y',int)])
>> c
array([(1, 2)], dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])
```

you are correct that

```
>> type(c) == type(c0)
True
```

but

```
>> c0.dtype.names
>> c0.dtype.names is None
True
>> c.dtype.names
('x', 'y')
>> c.dtype.names is None
False
```

allows you to see that `c` is a structured array while `c0` is not! This is also true of `np.recarray` types, but I haven't played around with those too much.

Answer (score 1):

When we load from disk the record array is always `np.ndarray` but then to automatically make those `np.ndarray` into `np.recarray` we still need something `isRecarray` function.

So in case when we load from disk to make any `numpy` record a `recarray` we need something. I assume `dtype.isbuiltin` will serve more useful in that case.

```py
x = np.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('x', float), ('y', int)])
x_rec = x.view(np.recarray)
np.save("x_rec.npy", x_rec)
x_rec_from_disk = np.load("x_rec.npy")

# still prints np.ndarray as recarray info is not saved
print(type(x_rec_from_disk))  

# so solution can be to rely on dtype.isbuiltin
if not x_rec_from_disk.dtype.isbuiltin:
    x_rec_from_disk = x_rec_from_disk.view(np.recarray)

# will print np.recarray
print(type(x_rec_from_disk))
```